# How to convert true type font to bitmap image?

Tags: c#, image, fonts, bitmap

I have a difficulty as I am trying to render a character with a specific font style to the bitmap image (black and white). My question is the font is basically black and white and I am writing the character in black (against white background), however when I convert it to bitmap image I get a coloured thin outline around the bindery of my character.

Can anyone tell me where that grey color comes from while I am writing it with black color and how can i get ONLY black and white pixels?

Comment: Probably anti-aliasing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing - it will look pretty crappy without it.

Comment: i have actually used that, doesn't work. my question is where does the grey color comes from in bitmap conversion. i was expecting to get pure black and white image!

Comment: @user3266873 see the `TextRenderingHint` property of graphics  you use. Change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pixels that aren't completely black or completely white are the result of anti-aliasing. Anti-aliasing is used by default since everyone who doesn't know about it probably wants it.

I suggest two alternatives. One, create your bitmap with a one bit per pixel format, which will not give anti-aliasing a chance. Second, you can go through the resulting image after the text has been drawn pixel by pixel and adjust each pixel to either black or white based on a threshold. I.e. if the picture is darker than half then it's black, otherwise it's white. e.g. if (red+green+blue > 383) set_pixel_white() else set_pixel_black(); But you'll need be ready for some rather funny results. You may need to play with the thresholds.

PS there's a better solution, you can tweak anti-aliasing. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) You'll set your rendering to System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel or something that suits you.

Comment: Martin,thank you for your comment. could you give me some idea of how to do the first option please?

Comment: The Bitmap constructor can take an extra parameter for the pixel format. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and the pixel format can be Format1bppIndexed [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Is this enough?

Comment: for the last thing, could you please give me an example of how using it as i have some problem?! many thanks

Comment: Try the link that I added to the answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx There's a nice example.

Comment: For me best results with 2 colors were using  drawing.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;